# HTTP Put Request using FormUrlEncodedContent

Tags: c#, http, put

I'm quite new to HTTP request and I need to perform HTTP request. I would also like to know where can I test my HTTP request after completing it. Here's the sample of the Put request:

> HTTP Method: PUT URL: 
> [https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/test/api/Sample/CloseSample?requestID={requestID}&mfgPartID={mfgPartID}](https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/test/api/Sample/CloseSample?requestID=%7BrequestID%7D&mfgPartID=%7BmfgPartID%7D)
>
> Sample:
> https://XXX.XX.XXX.XX/test/api/Sample/CloseSample?requestID=400088&mfgPartID=123

Here's what I've tried where I store the `request id` and `mfgPartID` in  `dictionary`with key and value pair:

```cs
public async void PutRequest(string URL,
                                     string key1, string value1,
                                     string key2, string value2)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> queries = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { key1, value1 },
                { key2, value2 }
            };
            HttpContent SendData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(queries);
            AddHeaderAuthorization();
            try
            {
                
                ResponseMessage = await client.PutAsync(URL, SendData);
                ResponseContent = ResponseMessage.Content;
                TestResponseMessage = await ResponseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                TestResponseMessage = "Update error";
            }
```

Also, ignore the `AddHeaderAuthorization` cause i'm sure that's functioning correctly.

Comment: Just put the URL into a browser.  The HTTPRequest gives same results as a browser but data is returned as text.  I browser simple as an additonal feature of viewing the results.

Comment: If you have a request you need a server that accepts the request.   So you can create a HTTP Listener that accepts non secure connections (HTTP not HTTPS) and then use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the request so you can verify the format and contents.